# Use setText to set EditText to null

Tags: android, eclipse

I did a search to see how to clear an EditText box and found a number of results, all agreeing. I create a variable for the box with:

```
final EditText fn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

and then I use setText thusly:

```
fn = setText("");
```

However when I implement this code in eclipse (with all the plug-ins and sdk's installed), I get the error: "The method setText(String) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener() {}"

What am I doing wrong? Was there some step I'm missing not mentioned in the other posts?

Comment: use `fn.setText("");` instead of `fn = setText("");`, search for tutorial and follow it if you really want to learn android.

Comment: That seems like it should work, but it's giving me the same error...

Comment: should not give you error, post your full code here please

Comment: And now it's not. Weird. But thank you!

Comment: yeah, error because you were doing it the wrong way.

Comment: use fn.setText(null); in steat of fn.setText("");

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness:

This part:

```
final EditText fn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

Is correct, provided that the layout of your currently running Activity contains a declaration for an EditText with the id "editText1", here is an example for such a layout file. This layout file is called "**my_layout**":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayoutxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

In your Activity you'd then have to call this method in your onCreate to set the above layout file as your Activity's layout file:

```
public abstract class MyActivity extends Activity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
   }
```

Given the above you can now reset the text in your EditText (called "fn" - see first code snipped):

```
fn.setText("");
```

The error you had, saying that the method setText does not exist in OnClickListener, probably stems from you trying to call setText("") within that OnClickListener. And as the error message explains: The OnClickListener knows nothing about a setText method - only the EditText knows about it, hence you need to call setText("") on the reference of your EditText.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are calling `setText` inside the code of a `Listener`. `"settext" = "this.settext"` and in this case this points to that listener. Try calling:

```
MyClassInWhichAllThisCodeIs.this.getThatEditTextRefference().setText("").
```

Comment: i asked a very clear and objective question! there are no more jobs that do not involve clean architecture. and they are all making applications so bad, clients are beginning to press charges.

Comment: The only objective part of your question was the resource request. Which is another explicitly off topic subject. Sorry. Our close system is bad at listing all of the issues with a post. Try crafting a question that follows all the rules.